# Removing duplicates from an array, using dynamic mem. allocation

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

This method is a member function of my class sets(for college), which has members,Set(pointer) and card(int)(cardinality).I am supposed to remove the duplicates and reduce the allocated memory.

The `nSet` pointer is being used to hold the data temporarily.

Unfortunately it is crashing, whenever called . Wat do?

```
void remdup() {
    int *nSet;
    for(int x=0;x<card-1;x++) {
        for(int y=x+1;y<card;y++) {
            if(Set[x]==Set[y]) {
                for(int g=y;g<card-1;g++) {
                    Set[g]=Set[g+1];
                } card--;
            }
        }
    }
    nSet=new int[card];
    for( int u=0;u<card;u++) {
        nSet[u]=Set[u];
    }
    delete Set;
    Set=new int[card];
    for(int u=0;card;u++) {
        Set[u]=nSet[u];
    }
```

Comment: `for(int u=0;card;u++)` should be `for(int u=0;u<card;u++)`

Comment: Replace all the code after `delete Set;` with `Set = nSet;`.

Comment: Have you run it in a debugger to find out?

Comment: Where is the program crashing and with what message?

Comment: What is "card(int)(cardinality)" supposed to mean? Instead of using made-up syntax, include the data members in the class definition.

Comment: @molbdnilo that doesn't seem to work, I'm getting garbage values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistake in your  for loop. `for(intialization;condition;increment)  {}`

```
void remdup() {
        int *nSet;
        for(int x=0;x<card-1;x++) {
            for(int y=x+1;y<card;y++) {
                if(Set[x]==Set[y]) {
                    for(int g=y;g<card-1;g++) {
                        Set[g]=Set[g+1];
                    } card--;
                }
                }
        }
        nSet=new int[card];
        for( int u=0;u<card;u++) {
            nSet[u]=Set[u];
        }
        delete Set;
        Set=new int[card];
        for(int u=0;u<card;u++) {<---
            Set[u]=nSet[u];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::set` instead of inventing another, substantially worse set.

Comment: I had to do it with arrays, prof's rule! It worked out though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend to use **`std::set`** instead of doing it yourself.
Apart from this if you change `for(int u=0;card;u++)`to `for(int u=0;u<card;u++)`, at the end of your code it will work.
But if you like to do all the work yourself and to shrink an array of `int`, you should use `std::memcpy` to copy the data from the old dynamic memory to the new one:

```
#include <cstring> // memcpy

int *nSet = new int[card];
std::memcpy( nSet, Set, card );
delete [] Set;
Set = nSet;
```